# What are the main differences and similarities between the christian heaven and moksha

Tags: moksha, atma, christianity

Hinduism and Christianity have few similarities. What are main similarities and differences in the concept of christianity heaven and Hindu moksha?
For example how to get there?

- What does it mean to a Hindu to achieve moksha?
- How much of a priority is it compared to christianity?

Comment: Christian Moksha state in heaven is similar to Salokya Moksha in Hinduism. (Salokya Mukti means getting eternal abode of Lord from where there is no return)...

Comment: Christians believe that they will live in their material bodies in heaven, that is why they try and preserve their physical bodies after death. The vedas assert that we live in a subtle body in the lokas. Moksha is final liberation where there is no more rebirths on earth. Unlike Christianity, where some souls are condemned to hell forever, Hindus assert that all will eventually be joined with the Lord.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a cross-religion question. See "Don'ts" in  http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross religious question.

Answer (score 1):

Swami Vivekananda states (Complete Works, V6 p 85 also V4 pp 188-9)

> The Vedas teach that the soul of man is immortal. The body is subject to the law of growth and decay; what grows must of necessity decay. But the indwelling spirit is related to the infinite and eternal life; it never had a beginning, and it will never have an end. One of the chief distinctions between the Vedic and the Christian religion is that the Christian religion teaches that each human soul had its beginning at its birth into this world; whereas the Vedic religion asserts that the spirit of man is an emanation of the Eternal Being and had no more a beginning than God Himself. Innumerable have been and will be its manifestations in its passage from one personality to another, subject to the great law of spiritual evolution, until it reaches perfection, when there is no more change.

Christians believe that they live one time and that they will be eventually be 'reunited' with their physical bodies and live with God in heaven. Hindus assert that we are spirit and that in the lokas we live in subtle bodies, not physical bodies. Moksha refers to final liberation from rebirth on this earth. What Moksha is beyond that depends upon which philosophy and sect you follow in Hinduism. Advaitists and Dvaitists have different beliefs to this.

There are no permanent hells in Hinduism as there is in Christianity. Everyone will eventually attain Moksha.

Comment: "There are no permanent hells in Hinduism as there is in Christianity."  Well, at least followers of Madhvacharya believe in a place of eternal punishment called Andhatamas, where souls who do bad deeds in birth after birth eventually end up.

Comment: As to your statement "Everyone will eventually attain Moksha.", some Sri Vaishnavas believe that souls who pursue Ekatva will be trapped in that state forever and thus be unable to attain actual Moksha.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan What is Ekatva?

Comment: Most Christians believe that they will be given a *new* heavenly body, not reunited with their old one. Some don't believe that at all, but most do. Regarding Hell, most Christians, again, believe in an eternal torment called Hell for the unrighteous. Some reject that entirely saying either the wicked are annihilated and cease to exist or there is *universal salvation*, meaning that all will go to heaven eventually. Can't comment on the Hindu part.

Comment: @fredsbend many believe that they will have a heavenly body until the end of the world occurs and they will be resurrected and their old bodies will be new again. Many variations between different sects and denominations I am sure. It was only recently (60 years ago) at the Second Vatican Council called by Pope John XXIII, that Catholics admitted that non-Catholics could go to heaven even if they were non-Christians if they lived an exemplary life. But Evangelicals, even today, say that you must accept Christ as your savior to go to heaven. Unaware of any denomination for universal salvation.

Answer (score 0):

#### Christian's Heaven and Moksha are almost same concept.

But [Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svarga) in Hinduism and [Moksha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moksha) have lot of difference.

Heaven is an after death [world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loka#Hindu_tradition). According to Hindu, Heaven and Moksha is there.

Heaven and Hell is maintained by lord Shiva. Souls went to heaven or hell will have rebirth in the earth in the form of anything(I mean any creature).

Moksha is provided by lord Vishnu. Souls that get Moksha will be shifted to Vaikundam and they don't have a rebirth.

The same is said by Christianity that heaven is the ultimate end.

Comment: Can you cite sources such as authentic Hindu Scriptures? For more details, visit [Can we revisit the sources required rule?](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/786/3500)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moksha details can be found in this link.